# Python Pandas - groupby difference with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like:

| Name | Age | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "John" | 20 | 1 |
| "John" | 23 | 0 |
| "Marie" | 21 | 1 |
| "John" | 26 | 1 |
| "Marie" | 28 | 0 |

I want to compute, for each row, the difference between the age of the person in this row and the last age of the same person in precedent rows that has the flag to 1. If there is no precedent row with flag to 1 for this person, I'm okay with 0. I'm expecting a serie like this as the output:

| Result |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 3 |
| 0 |
| **6** |
| 7 |

I would like to do something like:

```py
df
.groupby("Name")
.expanding()
.apply(custom_function)
```

Unfortunately, custom_function given to apply can only work on series, and I need to access the flag column to find the correct value to make my difference.

How can I tackle my problem, and is there a better solution for doing it ?

Comment: Is there a reason this is an _expanding_ window calculation? Also, can you provide a copy-paste-able CSV or Python code for this example data?

Comment: what is the definition of the "last age".....  what if the same name had the `flag` = 1 multiple times, which would be the correct "last age" in this event ?

Comment: @D.L I assumed in my answer that they are treating the rows as temporally ordered.

Comment: The rows are indeed temporarly ordered. I should have been more explicit !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute forcing it and writing a loop as @shadowtalker did is generally the way to go when you don't know where to start.

However in this case you can also use another approach.

Let's start by adding a column with the previous age, but only for rows with the flag:

```py
df["previous_age"] = df["age"].where(df["flag"] == 1)
df
```

```
  name  age  flag  previous_age
0    J   20     1            20
1    J   23     0          <NA>
2    M   21     1            21
3    J   26     1            26
4    M   28     0          <NA>
```

We can then fill the missing values using the "forward fill" method of `fillna` (inside a groupby/transform, to treat separately John and Mary).

```py
df["previous_age"] = df.groupby("name")["previous_age"].transform(lambda s: s.fillna(method="ffill"))
df
```

```
  name  age  flag  previous_age
0    J   20     1            20
1    J   23     0            20
2    M   21     1            21
3    J   26     1            26
4    M   28     0            21
```

We just need to shift these values by one position to get the right result for rows with the flag:

```py
df["previous_age"] = df.groupby("name")["previous_age"].transform(lambda s: s.shift(1))
df
```

```
  name  age  flag  previous_age
0    J   20     1          <NA>
1    J   23     0            20
2    M   21     1          <NA>
3    J   26     1            20
4    M   28     0            21
```

The `<NA>` values appear in the first rows for which we do not have a previous value.

And now we can substract:

```py
df["age"] - df["previous_age"]
```

```
0    <NA>
1       3
2    <NA>
3       6
4       7
dtype: Int64
```

If you prefer getting `0` instead of `<NA>` for the first row of every person, just add a backfill on top:

```py
df["previous_age"] = df.groupby("name")["previous_age"].transform(lambda s: s.fillna(method="bfill"))
df
df["age"] - df["previous_age"]
```

```
  name  age  flag  previous_age
0    J   20     1            20
1    J   23     0            20
2    M   21     1            21
3    J   26     1            20
4    M   28     0            21

0    0
1    3
2    0
3    6
4    7
dtype: Int64
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, and is a clear a well structured answer. Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['result'] = df['Age'] - df.sort_values('Flag', ascending=False).groupby('Name')['Age'].transform('min')
```

Output:

```
    Name  Age  Flag  result
0   John   20     1       0
1   John   23     0       3
2  Marie   21     1       0
3   John   26     1       6
4  Marie   28     0       7
```

Comment: Thanks, it does not answer my request exactly. It makes the difference with the min value for a given name, which is not what I want. If I had a new row with values ("John", 28, 1), I expect the serie to have be (0, 3, 0, 6, 7, 2), your function gives an (0, 3, 0, 6, 7, 8).

Answer (score 0):

Use the plain groupby-apply method, which gives you access to the entire group at once as a data frame. Then you can use the slow-but-valid brute force technique of looping through rows of each group.

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = '''
Name    Age     Flag
"John"  20  1
"John"  23  0
"Marie"     21  1
"John"  26  1
"Marie"     28  0
'''

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)
data.index.name = 'row_id'

def diff_in_group(grp):
    results = {}
    for i, (loc_curr, age_curr) in enumerate(grp['Age'].items()):
        grp_prev = grp.iloc[:i]
        grp_prev_ok = grp_prev.loc[grp_prev['Flag'] == 1]
        if len(grp_prev_ok) == 0:
            results[loc_curr] = 0
        else:
            age_prev_ok = grp_prev_ok['Age'].iat[-1]
            results[loc_curr] = age_curr - age_prev_ok
    return pd.Series(results).rename_axis(index=grp.index.name)

age_diffs = data.groupby('Name').apply(diff_in_group)

display(data)
print()
display(age_diffs)
```

```
         Name  Age  Flag
row_id
0        John   20     1
1        John   23     0
2       Marie   21     1
3        John   26     1
4       Marie   28     0

Name   row_id
John   0         0
       1         3
       3         6
Marie  2         0
       4         7
dtype: int64
```

There might be faster ways to do it, but sometimes it's best to just write a loop. You can make it performant and elegant *after* you get it working.